# Stack Search Chrome Extension

Tags: app, chrome-extensions

## Stack Search [image]

*A Google Chrome Context Menu Extension*

### Screenshot

[image]

### About [image]

This is a simple context menu extension that adds an option for selected text on a page to be searched on your favourite Stack Exchange sites.
The extension has two main components, the context menu list and the 'popup' page.

The 'popup' page is where the user selects the sites they wish to list in the context menu list.

#### License

[GNU GPL version 3](https://github.com/rlemon/StackSearch/blob/master/LICENSE.md)

#### Download

- [GitHub](https://github.com/rlemon/StackSearch)
- [Install](https://github.com/rlemon/StackSearch/raw/master/package.crx)

#### Platform

[Google Chrome](http://google.com/chrome)

### Contact

Created by [rlemon](http://stackexchange.com/users/440327)